# Find EC2 instances where tag value NOT equal value

Tags: amazon-ec2, tags, jq, aws-cli

I have a tag on my EC2 instances - backup_policy

It should be set to
"EC2_Prod_Daily_Weekly_Monthly" for prod accounts
"EC2_NonProd_Daily_Weekly_Monthly" for non-prod accounts
but sometimes prod may have the nonprod backup tag!

I need CLI or JQ where tag NOT EQUAL to value.

**Missing tag**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?!contains(Tags[].Key, backup_policy)][].InstanceId'
```

**With correct tag**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:backup_policy,Values=EC2_Prod_Daily_Weekly_Monthly --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?contains(Tags[].Key, backup_policy)].[InstanceId,Tags[?Key==Name].Value | [0],Tags[?Key==backup_policy].Value | [0]]' --output text
```

**Where NOT correct tag**

I've tried a LOT in jq.
e.g.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceId: InstanceId, Tags: Tags}' \
  --output json | 
  jq 'map(select(all(.Tags[]; .Key != "backup_policy" or .Value | contains("EC2_Prod_Daily_Weekly_Monthly") | not)))'
```

I need the instanceId and incorrect tag value (plus accountid which is also in my tags)

Here is example of json trying to parse:

```
[
    {
        "InstanceId": "i-03226b321aaff1122",
        "Tags": [
            {
            {
                "Key": "account_id",
                "Value": "1231231231"
            },
            {
                "Key": "backup_policy",
                "Value": "EC2_Prod_Daily_Weekly_Monthly-oldvalue"
            },
        ],
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks very much Paolo.
I did find this before, and it works fine for single values. I could not get it working for multiple. Probably I should have mentioned

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple" values?

Comment: got it working for multiple: 

`aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(any(.Tags[]; .Key == "backup_policy" and .Value == "EC2_type2_weekly_7_days_retention") or any(.Tags[]; .Key == "backup_policy" and .Value == "EC2_Prod_Daily_Weekly_Monthly") | not)' `

Comment: Great. Consider adding that as an answer as it could help other users in the future